# Setting a parameter as a list for an IN expression

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, jpql, toplink-essentials

Whenever I try to set a list as a parameter for use in an IN expression I get an Illegal argument exception. Various posts on the internet seem to indicate that this is possible, but it's certainly not working for me. I'm using Glassfish V2.1 with Toplink.

Has anyone else been able to get this to work, if so how?

here's some example code:

```
List<String> logins = em.createQuery("SELECT a.accountManager.loginName " +
    "FROM Account a " +
    "WHERE a.id IN (:ids)")
    .setParameter("ids",Arrays.asList(new Long(1000100), new Long(1000110)))
    .getResultList();
```

and the relevant part of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList for parameter accountIds with expected type of class java.lang.Long from query string SELECT a.accountManager.loginName FROM Account a WHERE a.id IN (:accountIds).
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EJBQueryImpl.setParameterInternal(EJBQueryImpl.java:663)
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:202)
at com.corenap.newtDAO.ContactDaoBean.getNotificationAddresses(ContactDaoBean.java:437)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1011)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:175)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:2920)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4011)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:203)
... 67 more
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your JPQL is invalid, remove the brackets

```
List<String> logins = em.createQuery("SELECT a.accountManager.loginName " +
    "FROM Account a " +
    "WHERE a.id IN :ids")
    .setParameter("ids",Arrays.asList(new Long(1000100), new Long(1000110)))
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately not - I had the same error.. we have Java EE 5, therefore EJB 3.0. From the Spec: "JSR 220: Enterprise JavaBeans,Version 3.0 - Java Persistence API" Section I see that "In" Expression requires brackets.. but then I was getting IllegalArgumentException when I set the parameter as a List<Integer>.. so I am using the awful hack below of expanding the IDs into a string of ORs (until I can get the proper JPA mappings in place with a DB View to avoid that).

Comment: Didn't work for me with .setParameter(), I had to use setParameterList()

Comment: How can a string like `var ids = "a1","b1",...;` be passed to java function and in turn to the IN operator?

Comment: @lukas84 That's because you're most likely using [hibernate Query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html) and not [persistence Query](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html)

Answer (score 20):

I found the answer, providing a list as a parameter is not supported in JPA 1.0; however, it is supported in JPA 2.0.

The default persistence provider for Glassfish v2.1 is Toplink which implements JPA 1.0, to get JPA 2.0 you need EclipseLink which is the default for the Glassfish v3 preview or can be plugged into v2.1.

-
Loren

Comment: Wrong. It depends upon implementation with JPA 1.0 implemented by Hibernate it work, but need brackets.

Comment: This used to be a bug in Hibernate: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5126

Answer (score 15):

Hope this helps some one. I have faced the issue and did the following to resolve (using eclipselink 2.2.0)

1. I had JavaEE jar as well as jpa 2 jar(javax.persistence*2*) in the class path. Removed the JavaEE from the class path.
2. I was using something like  `"  idItm IN  ( :itemIds ) "` which was throwing the exception :

> type class java.util.ArrayList for parameter itemIds with expected
>   type of class java.lang.String from query string

Solution: I just changed the in condition to  `"  idItm IN  :itemIds  "`, i.e. I removed the brackets ().

Comment: thanks a lot @dillip you saved my day. I just had to delete the parentheses around the parameter

Answer (score 2):

Simply, the parameter will be List and set it as

```
"...WHERE a.id IN (:ids)")
.setParameter("ids", yourlist)
```

This works for JPA 1.0

Answer (score 2):

**IN :ids** instead of  **IN (:ids)** - will work.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, and if you can't use EclipseLink for some reason then here is a method you can use to add the needed bits to your query.  Just insert the resulting string into your query where you would put "a.id IN (:ids)".

```java
    /** 
     * @param field The jpql notation for the field you want to evaluate
     * @param collection The collection of objects you want to test against
     * @return Jpql that can be concatenated into a query to test if a feild is in a collection of objects
     */
    public String in(String field, List collection) {
        String queryString = new String();
        queryString = queryString.concat(" AND (");
        int size = collection.size();
        for(int i = 0; i &gt size; i++) {
            queryString = queryString.concat(" "+field+" = '"+collection.get(i)+"'");
            if(i &gt size-1) {
                queryString = queryString.concat(" OR");
            }
        }
        queryString = queryString.concat(" )");
        return queryString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NamedQuery instead:

```
List<String> logins = em.createNamedQuery("Account.findByIdList").setParameter("ids", Arrays.asList(new Long(1000100), new Long(1000110))).getResultList();
```

Add the named query to your entity

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Account.findByIdList", query = "SELECT a.accountManager.loginName FROM Account a WHERE a.id IN :ids")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code instead of the one supplied by @Szymon Tarnowski to add the OR list.. *warning* if you have hundreds of IDs though, you might break whatever limit is in place regarding the max length of a query.

```
/**
 * @param field
 *           The jpql notation for the field you want to evaluate
 * @param collection
 *           The collection of objects you want to test against
 * @return Jpql that can be concatenated into a query to test if a feild is
 *         in a collection of objects
 */
public static String in(String field, List<Integer> idList) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append(" AND (");
  for(Integer id : idList) {
    sb.append(" ").append(field).append(" = '").append(id).append("'").append(" OR ");
  }
  String result = sb.toString();
  result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 4); // Remove last OR
  result += ")";
  return result;
}
```

To test this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(122);
  list.add(132);
  list.add(112);
  System.out.println(in("myfield", list));
}
```

Which gave output: 
    AND ( myfield = '122' OR  myfield = '132' OR  myfield = '112')

Comment: Repeat after me: "I will never ever use StringBuilders or other similar techniques to build SQL queries as this enables SQL injection. I will only use prepared statements and such."

Comment: Thank you for the warning about potential vulnerabilities with SQL @siebz0r. However I do not believe this is valid here. Prepared statements can't be used as the number of args are not known and the version of JPA doesn't allow list args. Also, the arguments here are not from public input and they are cast as Integer objects.

Comment: I understand the risks are limited, but still, weird things can happen. `java.sql.PreparedStatement` can be used for such rare cases. This interface supports collections as a parameter.

Answer (score -3):

You can also try this syntax.

```
static public String generateCollection(List list){
    if(list == null || list.isEmpty())
        return "()";
    String result = "( ";
    for(Iterator it = list.iterator();it.hasNext();){
        Object ob = it.next();
        result += ob.toString();
        if(it.hasNext())
            result += " , ";
    }
    result += " )";
    return result;
}
```

And put into query, `"Select * from Class where field in " + Class.generateCollection(list);`

Comment: No, no, no. This is will enable SQL injection possibilities.