# Adding IN clause List to a JPA Query

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have built a NamedQuery that looks like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "EventLog.viewDatesInclude",
        query = "SELECT el FROM EventLog el WHERE el.timeMark >= :dateFrom AND "
        + "el.timeMark <= :dateTo AND "
        + "el.name IN (:inclList)")
```

What I want to do is fill in the parameter :inclList with a list of items instead of one item.  For example if I have a `new List<String>() { "a", "b", "c" }` how do I get that in the :inclList parameter?  It only lets me codify one string.   For example:

```
setParameter("inclList", "a") // works

setParameter("inclList", "a, b") // does not work

setParameter("inclList", "'a', 'b'") // does not work

setParameter("inclList", list) // throws an exception
```

I know I could just build a string and build the whole Query from that, but I wanted to avoid the overhead.   Is there a better way of doing this?

Related question: if the List is very large, is there any good way of building query like that?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557085/setting-a-parameter-as-a-list-for-an-in-expression#7967570 but this thread provides useful answers.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

When using `IN` with a collection-valued parameter you  don't need `(...)`:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "EventLog.viewDatesInclude", 
    query = "SELECT el FROM EventLog el WHERE el.timeMark >= :dateFrom AND " 
    + "el.timeMark <= :dateTo AND " 
    + "el.name IN :inclList")
```

Comment: Nope ... I my case its opposite. If I use :inclList then its not working. If I use  IN (:inclList) then it works.

Comment: Also note mentioning: the type of your param has to be an collection (not an array) of objects. The objects must match the type of the field. .toString() is no substitute for class String

Comment: I think this is something that has changed with the versions of Hibernate, as far as I can remember I have gotten an error when not having the paranthesis around the variable when using IN. Strange if it's not backwards compatible..

Comment: This was indeed an hibernate bug (the need of parenthesis) that's been fixed in 3.6.1

Comment: For related question: In case of very large list there could be limitations for the in implementation. E.g. oracle 11g. max. 1000 list elements as parameter are possible. A workaround is to chop the list in subLists and collect the results. JPA itself does not restrict the list size.

Comment: It did work. Thanks for that. Now, how do I make this an optional filter? `:inclList IS NULL OR el.name IN : inclList` throws `QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node` because it concatenates the whole list in the first part as well.

Answer (score 107):

The proper JPA query format would be:

```
el.name IN :inclList
```

If you're using an older version of Hibernate as your provider you have to write:

```
el.name IN (:inclList)
```

but that is a bug ([HHH-5126](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5126)) (EDIT: which has been resolved by now).

Comment: Thank you for distinguishing the older versions of Hibernate use ()

Answer (score 38):

```
public List<DealInfo> getDealInfos(List<String> dealIds) {
        String queryStr = "SELECT NEW com.admin.entity.DealInfo(deal.url, deal.url, deal.url, deal.url, deal.price, deal.value) " + "FROM Deal AS deal where deal.id in :inclList";
        TypedQuery<DealInfo> query = em.createQuery(queryStr, DealInfo.class);
        query.setParameter("inclList", dealIds);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Works for me with JPA 2, Jboss 7.0.2

Comment: Thank you for showing a brief but complete example.

Answer (score 22):

You should convert to `List` as shown below:

```
    String[] valores = hierarquia.split(".");       
    List<String> lista =  Arrays.asList(valores);
    
    String jpqlQuery = "SELECT a " +
            "FROM AcessoScr a " +
            "WHERE a.scr IN :param ";
    
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(jpqlQuery, AcessoScr.class);                   
    query.setParameter("param", lista);     
    List<AcessoScr> acessos = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thx this answer helped me

Comment: This is best answer.