# IN-clause in HQL or Java Persistence Query Language

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I have the following parametrised JPA, or Hibernate, query:

```
SELECT entity FROM Entity entity WHERE name IN (?)
```

I want to pass the parameter as an ArrayList<String>, is this possible? Hibernate current tells me, that

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Is this possible at all?

**ANSWER**: Collections as parameters only work with named parameters like "`:name`", not with JDBC style parameters like "`?`".

Comment: Would you mind adding your answer to this question?  I know it's an old one, but self-answering your question is not only permitted, it's explicitly encouraged.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Are you using Hibernate's `Query` object, or JPA? For JPA, it should work fine:

```
String jpql = "from A where name in (:names)";
Query q = em.createQuery(jpql);
q.setParameter("names", l);
```

For Hibernate's, you'll need to use the setParameterList:

```
String hql = "from A where name in (:names)";
Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
q.setParameterList("names", l);
```

Comment: Okey, the problem was using ? to designate the parameters. With named parameters like :peter this works.

Comment: so you don't need the quotes for each string in the list?

Comment: How to set String[] array as query parameter

Comment: you could convert it to a list: `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(yourArray);`

Comment: IMP: Parenthesis are required for older versions of hibernate. Newer versions will not support () - at least in my case. Also, see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/21341663/6043669

Comment: Boom, champion!

Answer (score 24):

in HQL you can use query parameter and set Collection with setParameterList method.

```
    Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT entity FROM Entity entity WHERE name IN (:names)");
    q.setParameterList("names", names);
```

Answer (score 5):

Leaving out the parenthesis and simply calling 'setParameter' now works with at least Hibernate.

```
String jpql = "from A where name in :names";
Query q = em.createQuery(jpql);
q.setParameter("names", l);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using pure JPA with *Hibernate 5.0.2.Final* as the actual provider the following seems to work with positional parameters as well:

Entity.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "byAttributes", query = "select e from Entity e where e.attribute in (?1)") })
public class Entity {
    @Column(name = "attribute")
    private String attribute;
}
```

Dao.java:

```
public class Dao {
    public List<Entity> findByAttributes(Set<String> attributes) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("byAttributes");
        query.setParameter(1, attributes);

        List<Entity> entities = query.getResultList();
        return entities;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

query.setParameterList("name", new String[] { "Ron", "Som", "Roxi"}); fixed my issue