# Is there a way to do a "in" statment in javax.persistence.Query

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IN-clause in HQL or Java Persistence Query Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828049/in-clause-in-hql-or-java-persistence-query-language)

I.E. could i do something like say
Select * from foo where bar in (1,2,3,4)

but using the Query.parameter function?

Comment: This looks like it has already been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828049/in-clause-in-hql-or-java-persistence-query-language. I hope that helps some. It looks like it is poissble.