# Specifying list parameter in HQL NOT IN clause

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I've got the following code to set a `List` parameter in a `NOT IN` clause in an HQL query

```
private static final String FIND_AVAILABLE_OPERATORS = "FROM Domain domain WHERE domain.type = :type AND domain.operators NOT IN (:operators)";

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Domain> findAvailableOperators(Domain domain) {
    Query query = null;
    if (domain.getOperators().isEmpty()) {
        query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(FIND_BY_DOMAIN_TYPE); // run another query
    } else {
        query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(FIND_AVAILABLE_OPERATORS);
        query.setParameterList("operators", domain.getOperators());
    }

    query.setParameter("type", DomainType.OPERATOR);
    return query.list();
}
```

but I get an `SQLGrammarException` when my `List` is not empty

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: No value specified for parameter 2
```

Am I using the `setParameterList()` [incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828049/in-clause-in-hql-or-java-persistence-query-language)?

The SQL executed seems to be

```
Hibernate: select domain0_.domain_id as domain1_2_, domain0_.country as country2_, domain0_.name as name2_, domain0_.type as type2_ from domain domain0_ cross join domain_operators operators1_, domain domain2_ where domain0_.domain_id=operators1_.parent and operators1_.child=domain2_.domain_id and (. not in  (?)) and domain0_.type=?
```

I've never seen `(. not in  (?))`.

EDIT: My `Domain` entity

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Domain {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "domain_id")
    private Long domainId;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DomainType type;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "domain_id")
    }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "code")
    })
    private Set<NetworkCode> networkCodes = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent", referencedColumnName = "domain_id")
    }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "child", referencedColumnName = "domain_id")
    })
    private Set<Domain> operators = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Country country;

    public Domain() {}
        ... setters/getters
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you can see in [the HQL reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3400), the `[not] in` predicate works only with single value expressions.

You will have to use a query such as:

```
private static final String FIND_AVAILABLE_OPERATORS = "SELECT d FROM Domain as d LEFT OUTER JOIN d.operators as o WHERE d.type = :type AND o.domainID not in (:operators)";
```

You then can build a `List<Long>` with just the `domain.getOperators()` IDs and use it in the `setParameterList()` method.