# Get objects form database using hibernate with two list as parameters

Tags: java, sql, performance, hibernate

I'm trying to get results from database iterating over two collection as shown below

```
for (SomeType element1 in List1) {
    for (SomeType2 element2 in List2) {
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Table where column1 =: element1 and column2 =: element2");
        //Operations on list of results
    }
}
```

How can I do something like this with best performance? In my app list1 has 200 elements and list2 around 30 and it takes too much time.

Comment: This is horrible for performance. You're executing 200 * 30 queries given your lists size. 

Use HQL [IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828049/in-clause-in-hql-or-java-persistence-query-language) clause instead.

Comment: Can I use two HQL 'ins' in one query? For example:
`from Table where column1 in (:list1) and column2 in (:list2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Table where column1 IN (:List1) and column2 IN (:List2)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but it can do the job:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
for (SomeType element1 in List1) {
    for (SomeType2 element2 in List2) {
        sb.append(element1).append(',').append(element2).append("),");
    }
}
// delete the last ','
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
Query query = session.createQuery(
  "from Table where (column1, column2) in ("+sb.toString+")"
);
```