# JPQL IN clause with other parameter, using ordinal parameters

Tags: jpa, parameters, jpql, ordinal

I'm having a problem with named querys, using ordinal parameters and the IN clause.

This is my Named Query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Photo.getByIds", query = "FROM Photo i WHERE i.User.idUser = ?1 AND i.idPhoto IN ?2")
```

This is the code to get the list of photos:

```
TypedQuery<Photo> q = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Photo.getByIds", Photo.class);

q.setParameter(1, 50);
q.setParameter(2, Arrays.asList(50, 51));

List<Photo> photoList = q.getResultList();
```

And that's the error I keep getting:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter does not appear in Query: 1 [FROM entity.Photo i WHERE i.User.idUser = ?1 AND i.idPhoto IN (:x20_, :x21_)] <java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter does not appear in Query: 1 [FROM entity.Photo i WHERE i.User.idUser = ?1 AND i.idPhoto IN (:x20_, :x21_)]>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter does not appear in Query: 1 [FROM br.gov.sus.cadsus.entity.CadsusImagemFoto i WHERE i.cadsusFotografia.coSeqFotografia = ?1 AND i.coSeqImagem IN (:x20_, :x21_)]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1376)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255)

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter does not appear in Query: 1 [FROM entity.Photo i WHERE i.User.idUser = ?1 AND i.idPhoto IN (:x20_, :x21_)]
at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.getNamedParameterLocs(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:551)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindNamedParameters(Loader.java:1910)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1845)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1716)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:940)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)
... 25 more
```

What's wrong? I checked the syntax of these methods/functions/jpql, and everything seems ok.
I also tried using named parameters, and it worked. But that's not a soluting for me. I need to use ordinal parameters.

Someone has a clue?

Comment: Is Photo defined with a mapped User class?  Which part of the query causes an error?  i.User.idUser = ?1 or i.idPhoto IN ?2 or both?

Comment: Yes, Photo is defined with a mapping to User.
The exact query causes the error. I tried with just one of the parameters, and both worked isolated. But not together...

Comment: Odd, yes.  The query "FROM entity.Photo i WHERE i.User.idUser = ?1 AND i.idPhoto IN (:x20_, :x21_)" has an ordinal param and 2 named params , :x20_ and :x21_.  That's why the exception is raised.  Try surrounding ?2 with parenths, like (?2).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378824/adding-in-clause-list-to-a-jpa-query

Comment: I tried doing what you said. Got the same error....

Answer (score 1):

Select is missing.
Query should be

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Photo.getByIds", query = "SELECT i FROM Photo i WHERE i.User.idUser = ?1 AND i.idPhoto IN ?2")
```