# jpa named query : named bind variables for list

Tags: java, sql, jpa

if you have a namedquery with a list like :

```
@NamedQuery(name="selection" , query=" SELECT x FROM Employee x WHERE x.name IN ('Jack', 'Jill')")
```

is it possible to make the list to named bind variables so you set what you want with :

```
q.setParameter( .......  );
```

Any suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just do it like for any other parameter:

```
@NamedQuery(name="selection" , query=" SELECT x FROM Employee x WHERE x.name IN :names")

q.setParameter("names", Arrays.asList("Jack", "Jill"));
```

Comment: Parenthesis not required? Other answer includes them – Found some details over at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21341663/1146608)

Answer (score 2):

Use this way

```
@NamedQuery(name="selection" , query=" SELECT x FROM Employee x WHERE x.name IN (:availableCollection)") 


namesCollection // conatains your Lsit of names

query.setParameterList('availableCollection', namesCollection);
```