# Create a namedQuery to get filtered result

Tags: jpa, named-query

How can I set a parameter as a list of values in a named query, so I can get a filtered resultSet from database?

For example: I want a resultSet which contains only data filtered by code 1, 2, and 3.

In SQL, the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM PontoEletronico WHERE prefDep IN (1, 2, 3);
```

As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378824/adding-in-clause-list-to-a-jpa-query), my namedQuery actually is:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "PontoEletronico.findAllEscritorios", query = "SELECT p FROM PontoEletronico p WHERE p.prefDep IN :myList");
```

The myList is set as below:

```
List<PrefDeps> myList;
private final PrefDeps p1 = new PrefDeps();
private final PrefDeps p2 = new PrefDeps();

    public List<T> findAllEscritorios() {
    p1.setPrefDep(9882);
    p2.setPrefDep(9517);
    myList.add(p1);
    myList.add(p2);
    return (List<T>) getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("PontoEletronico.findAllEscritorios", PontoEletronico.class).setParameter("prefDep", myList).getResultList();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `"myList"` as key of `setParameter` call::

```
return (List<T>) getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("PontoEletronico.findAllEscritorios", PontoEletronico.class).setParameter("myList", myList).getResultList();
```

From `javax.persistence.Query`:

```
/**
 * Bind an argument value to a named parameter.
 * @param name  parameter name
 * @param value  parameter value
 * @return the same query instance
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the parameter name does 
 *         not correspond to a parameter of the query or if
 *         the argument is of incorrect type
 */
Query setParameter(String name, Object value);
```

So, in your query called the pararameter `:myList` you should use the same key on `setParameter`.

Good luck!