# SPRING|Java - Use IN clause with SpEl in query

Tags: java, jpa, spring-el, in-clause

I got an enum (ClubRole) which got a method returning a collection of values from this enum. I trying to call this method from inside the query using SpEl.

```java
 @Query("select m from ClubMember m " +
    "where m.student = :student " +
    "and m.role in :#{#role.getParents()}"
  )
  List<ClubMember> findByRoleWithInheritance(@Param("student") Student student, @Param("role") ClubRole role);
```

This passes the build, and the application runs but when this method's called I got ``No parameter binding found for name role!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parameter binding found for name role!

I tried different ways but none worked. I would like to know if it's possible to use SpEl in this situation, and if so how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is an issue in spring-data-jpa. I could see people discussing same issue on spring-blog. Not sure whether there is an open issue for this.
You can try following as a workaround.

```
@Query("select m from ClubMember m " +
    "where m.student = :#{#student}" +
    "and m.role in :#{#role.getParents()}"
  )
  List<ClubMember> findByRoleWithInheritance(@Param("student") Student student, @Param("role") ClubRole role);
```

Or you can try with index access for second parameter like `#{[1].getParents()}`

[this](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) might help.

Comment: If your issue is resolved can you please mark it as accepted? .It will help others as well.

Comment: just did. However the solution is very specific to my problem so i don't know if it'll help others. The "error" if it's one is extremely odd

Comment: Thanks!! your are not the first one to get this error though :) I'll open an issue for this

Comment: Good call, i too found a lot of similar issue concerning IN clause with SpEL. This topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127723/spring-data-jpa-query-with-spel-in-a-in-query talked about a issue but it's was supposedly fixed.