# How do you write a query for SELECT IN

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Here is the query that I'm trying to get to work on Spring 4 with Hibernate and JPA. How do you write a query for SELECT IN?

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM DaybookCalendar d WHERE uuid IN ? ")
public List<DaybookCalendar> findByUuids(List<String> calendarIds);
```

Comment: You may need to generate the bind placeholders (`?`) dynamically. See for example [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause).

Comment: Might also be that JPA allows passing in the `List` directly. See [Adding IN clause to JPA query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378824/adding-in-clause-list-to-a-jpa-query)