# How to pass objects or grouped params to SQL IN clause?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I need using JPA to find records by matching 2 grouped parameters from a table but my problem is that I don't know how to pass an object or grouped parameter in SQL, if that is possible at all.

Let's say we have the User table:

```
USER_TABLE

name VARCHAR,
email VARCHAR,
address VARCHAR
```

I need to find all users where grouped name and email match. Something like this:

```
SELECT FROM USER_TABLE 
WHERE (name, email) 
IN (('John', 'john@mail'), ('Oliver', 'oliver@mail'));
```

It works in SQL tool but now I need to use this SQL from Java

To do so I udpated it to accept a parameter

```
SELECT FROM USER_TABLE 
WHERE (name, email) 
IN (?);
```

So my question is HOW do I pass parameters or so that they will be grouped?

I tried to create a parameter as it is below but it won't work because it is not a valid type

```
String param = "('John', 'john@mail'), ('Oliver', 'oliver@mail')";
db.execute(sql, param)
```

Is that possible at all?

Comment: Try without the external brackets as suggested  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378824/adding-in-clause-list-to-a-jpa-query

Comment: @MShaposhnik it doesn't work. It is not the brackets that causes the issue but the grouping of 2 paramters as a single one. I will probably use StringBuilder as it seems the only way to do it. Not that secured but the only way. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it this way:

```
SELECT FROM USER_TABLE 
WHERE (name, email) 
IN ((?, ?), (?, ?));
```

Each parameter takes the place of a *single scalar value*, not a list of values, and not any other SQL syntax like parentheses. You need to put all the parens into your prepared statement, then use parameters only for the values.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I will do this way.

Answer (score -3):

use jpa Query,something like that:

@Query("select * from User  s where  s.id in (:ids)")

Page methodName(@Param(value = "ids") List ids);

Comment: Which is NOT a JPQL query. There is no "*" in JPQL. And the rest of it is SPRING DATA, which is not mentioned in the question

Comment: And where is the grouping?