# Does JPA criteria api have a problem with JOIN and IN?

Tags: sql, jpa, left-join

This is a JPA Query question. I have successfully used "LEFT JOIN" and "IN:" in EntityManager.CreateQuery in separate situations, but when i combine the two e.g.

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM TableA a 
  LEFT JOIN TableB b on a.myAField = b.id and b.myBField in :Ids 
  LEFT JOIN TableC c on b.myBOtherField = c.id
```

where Ids is `List<Long>` it starts giving me this error **"The left parenthesis is missing from the IN expression."**

The sql works fine when pasted directly into postGres pgAdmin explicitly writing out the parameters. Have I made a mistake with the syntax here or is this a jpa limitation and i need an alternative?

```
        List<Long> myBFieldTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        myBFieldTypes.add(5L);
        myBFieldTypes.add(10L);

        try {
            List<Long> resultArray = em.createQuery("SELECT a.id FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b on a.myAField = b.id and b.myBField in :Ids LEFT JOIN TableC c on b.myBOtherField = c.id")
                    .setParameter("Ids", myBFieldTypes)
                    .getResultList();
            return resultArray;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
```

Comment: The error is correct. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Why is the error correct?  `WHERE IN` with a bound parameter is supposed to work in JPA, as far as I know.

Comment: You should show us the full relevant Java code, in particular, the place where you bind your list to the parameter.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, no parentheses needed?

Comment: @jarlh No, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378824/adding-in-clause-list-to-a-jpa-query

Comment: @jarlh PostgreSQL, parenthesis work correctly with WHERE IN when not part of a LEFT

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen edited to show code.

Comment: ADDITIONAL NOTE : On further testing, if you remove the second LEFT JOIN on Table C, there is no missing parenthesis error, it is when there is a LEFT JOIN after an IN where the incorrect parenthesis error occurs