# JPA Query with variable OR expressions

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a situation where I need to extract purchase records based on User's Cards (**number of cards would vary from user to user**) using JPA.

The equivalent SQL query would be something like:
`select * FROM Purchase WHERE cardId=10 OR cardId=1 OR.... ORDER BY purchasedate desc;`

My DAO method signature is:

```
public List<Purchase> getPurchases(List<Card> cardsList)
```

I believe that I will have to use criteria query but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

Comment: Take a look at this post : [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378824/adding-in-clause-list-to-a-jpa-query)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `IN` statement instead of multiple `OR`s

`select * FROM Purchase WHERE cardId in(1, 10) ORDER BY purchasedate desc`

So you can use

`public List<Purchase> getAllByCardIdIn(List<Long> cardIds)`