# SQL Script doesn't return the value from the Oracle database in Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

> I have created a JPA query to read the view from the oracle database in Spring Boot.
> It works if I set a literal value to the POLICY_REF like **POLICY_REF IN ('A123I')** then View returns the policy. In the log

ids: [A123I]
query: [A123I]

otherwise it returns empty if I set **POLICY_REF IN (:ids).**

ids: [A123I]
query: []

> ids value is coming from the UI that is set to - ids: [A123I]

Please, any suggestion?

```
public HashSet<String> memberExists(final List<String> ids) {
    log.info("ids: "+ids);
    return new HashSet<String>(
            this.testJdbcTemplate
                    .query("select TRIM(POLICY_REF) from LSCHEMA.POLICY_VIEW where POLICY_REF in (:ids)",
                   Collections.singletonMap("ids", ids), this.rowMapper));
}

public boolean memberExists(final String id) {
    
    return this.memberExists(Collections.singletonList(id))
            .contains(id);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the () you have put in the query after IN clause

Maybe this question would be of help  [Adding IN clause List to a JPA Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378824/adding-in-clause-list-to-a-jpa-query)