# HSQL reference custom type in jdbc create array statement

Tags: java, sql, arrays, jdbc, hsqldb

I currently get an SQLException when invoking the [createArrayOf(String,Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) of the Connection class.  My database is HSQL and the code used to generate the type is as follows:

```
create type FOO as BIGINT;
```

The java code I am invoking is as follows:

```
Connection conn = createConnection();  
conn.createArrayOf("MySchema.FOO",data);
```

This also fails:

```
Connection conn = createConnection();  
conn.createArrayOf("FOO",data);
```

The resulting output is:

> Invalid argument in JDBC call: FOO

My question is how can I bind to a type that exists in a HSQL database, this is **not** an in memory instance.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557085/setting-a-parameter-as-a-list-for-an-in-expression ?

Comment: @Chris I am not using JPA nor am I using the IN syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User defined types are not currently supported as arguments to this method. You can use "BIGINT". Future versions of HSQLDB may support user defined type arguments.

Comment: Good to know.  Hope they change that.