# passing list to in clause but not work in jpql

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, jpql

Please solve my problem i am trying to run these jpql

the code is that

```
List<Jewellery> jewelleries;
List<Seller> searchedSellers;  
List<Integer> jewelleryIds;
jewelleries = entityManager
                .createQuery(
                   "SELECT j FROM Jewellery j WHERE j.id = (SELECT jt.id FROM  JewelleryType jt WHERE jt.type = :type)",
        Jewellery.class)
        .setParameter("type", jewelleryType).getResultList();
for (Jewellery j : jewelleries) {
    jewelleryIds.add(j.getId());
}
searchedSellers = entityManager
    .createQuery(
        "SELECT s FROM Seller s WHERE (s.city.id = (SELECT c.id FROM City c WHERE c.city = :parameter1 )) AND (s.jewellery.id in (:parameter2))",
        Seller.class)
        .setParameter("parameter1", city)
        .setParameter("parameter2", jewelleryIds).getResultList();
```

i found following error in console.log file

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.ArrayList for parameter
 parameter2 with expected type of class java.lang.Integer from query 
 string SELECT s FROM Seller s WHERE (s.city.id = (SELECT c.id FROM City c WHERE c.city = :parameter1 )) AND (s.jewellery.id in (:parameter2))
```

please solve the issue.
thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting a parameter as a list for an IN expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557085/setting-a-parameter-as-a-list-for-an-in-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your JPQL Query is invalid, you have to remove brakets for IN clause like :

```
SELECT s FROM Seller s WHERE (s.city.id = (SELECT c.id FROM City c WHERE c.city = :parameter1 )) AND (s.jewellery.id in :parameter2)
```