# JPA IN-Parameter

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I create a query like this in JPA (EclipseLink)

```
Query selectQuery = ... and SUBSTR(FOO, 0, 1) IN (?1)
```

or

```
Query selectQuery = ... and SUBSTR(FOO, 0, 1) IN ?1
```

I set a parameter like this:

```
selectQuery.setParameter(1, Arrays.asList(new String[] { "T" }));
```

However it is telling me
`invalid column type`

When I change my query to this:

```
Query selectQuery = ... and SUBSTR(FOO, 0, 1) IN ('T')
```

it works as expected.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a parameter as a list for an IN expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557085/setting-a-parameter-as-a-list-for-an-in-expression)

Comment: Nope, same exception!

Comment: Where is the exception coming from, JPA or the database?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate. The answer, anyway, is to use `SUBSTR(FOO, 0, 1) IN ?1` without the parantheses.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list as a parameter, thus you should use the `setParameterList` method:

```
selectQuery.setParameterList(1, Arrays.asList(new String[] { "T" }));
```

Comment: `javax.persistence.Query` does not have `setParameterList`